# How do I use java to simulate CURL transfer parameters?

Tags: java, curl

```
// curl -v -S -u root:abc123456 -F'notification={"applicationId":"229396","schemaId":"229506","topicId":"98315","type":"USER"};type=application/json' "http://wy.com/" | python -mjson.tool

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
StringBody comment = new StringBody(param,ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
reqEntity.addPart("notification", comment);
post.setEntity(reqEntity);
post.addHeader("Authorization", getHeader(authString));
```

Above is my curl and Java code.

I have already set up notification type, but when running, there are still 400 of the error prompts:

```
400
Required request part 'notification' is not present
```

Is there anyone who can help me see where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved

```
StringBody comment = new StringBody(param,ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Change to the following one

```
StringBody comment = new StringBody(param,ContentType.create("application/json"));
```

And, HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE
remove

The test passed successfully